# Pageable.getSort() is always null on the server side

Tags: spring, sorting, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am working on a web app using Spring MVC 3.2.5 and Spring Data Commons 1.4.1. Pageable is used in a controller to handle pagination, which is working. I'm trying to get sorting to work, but Pageable.getSort() always returns null for some reason.

Besides pagination related fields (pageNumber=1&pageSize=10, I also tried passing the following field(s) for Pageable.getSort() from a JSP page, but none works. So how can I fix this issue? Thanks.

1. sort=field1,desc
2. sort=field1&sort.dir=desc
3. page.sort=field1&page.sort.dir=desc

Answer (score 1):

According to official Sping Data Commons documentation

> Properties that should be sorted by in the format
>   property,property(,ASC|DESC). Default sort direction is ascending. Use
>   multiple sort parameters if you want to switch directions, e.g.
>   ?sort=firstname&sort=lastname,asc.

So it's 1st, unless you want to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, which made me realize that what I did in my app was wrong. Btw, according to  [Spring Data Commons 1.4.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/#web-pagination), only the 3rd option above is supported by default although the 2nd option may also work with a few changes to the configuration of PageableArgumentResolver.

Comment: The 1st option above is supported in [Spring Data Commons 1.8.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.8.x/reference/htmlsingle/#web-pagination) and later versions.

Comment: I was looking at the latest documentation :)